# tooltip jquery plugin is not working in a single page with IE?

Tags: jquery, plugins

I'm using the [plugin tooltipster](http://iamceege.github.io/tooltipster/) to create some tool tips in my web page.

I created a test page and it works fine with IE8 however when I put the same code in the page of my website it simply does not work in IE8 (however it still works in chrome).

I tried to debug it for hours and nothing seems to work.

What could be the cause of this?

Answer (score 1):

Wherefrom do you link your jquery source? From an CDN or from a directory within your web site?

If you link from an external source you may get an info from the IE that some activeX is trying to access the page and you have to accept the message.

Otherwise you could post a little bit more info about your website composition and source code.

Cheers,
Martin

Comment: I'm linking from my local server directly from a directory within my site. Sometimes this message appears but even when I accept it nothing happens..

Comment: As to the code I don't know if that would help, it is too long and I don't know which piece could be useful.. Thanks anyway =) Man I have reduced my site to a link for trying to find the bug but nothing =(

Comment: A further information is that a message sometimes appear and says it is being executed in compatibility exhibition mode..maybe that is the problem. I can't think nothing else by now. All I know is that I hate ie..

Comment: What version are you using? You could pass a meta tag to set the compatibility for IE: <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=11"/>

Comment: Well I was using version ie 8..I guess I solved my problem, I started reconstructing all the code from scratch copying and pasting of course and now the problem is gone and apparently it was caused by the use of another plugin..

Comment: Indeed that wasn't the use of another plugin, I added them again and it worked fine, so the conclusion is that I don't know what was wrong but I solved it rescontructing all the code, maybe I did something different now and I didn't notice =)